# How can I create a python object based on a variable name?

Tags: python, flask, session

I'm using Flask to build a chat interface to the Google Cloud Large Language Model (Palm2). In order to support multiple concurrent users, I need to create a different chat object for each user so they maintain their own context. To achieve this I am generating a uuid for each user, and I would like to create the chat object based on `session['sessionid']`, but I can't figure out how to do it! I've read about variable variables and looked at dictionaries, but after several hours looking at this I still can't work it out, and I'm sure there is a simple solution! Here is the snippet:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    if session.get('sessionid'):
        print ('sessionid already set: ',session['sessionid'])
    else: session['sessionid'] = uuid.uuid4().hex
    chat = chat_model.start_chat()
    return redirect(url_for('chat'))
```

You can see on line 6 I create the chat object, but I need to base the object name on the session uuid to ensure it it unique for each user.

I then need to make a call to the LLM using that object, you can see in the below snippet I'm calling it chat, but again, this actually need to be based on `session['sessionid']` :

```
response = chat.send_message(user_input, **parameters)
```

If anyone can help me understand how to do this I will be eternally grateful, I've been looking at this for hours and I'm at my wits end!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I need to base the object name on the session uuid to ensure it it unique for each user." That's not true. The variable's name has **no** bearing on uniqueness of an actual object.
Try the following:

Create a dictionary of chats outside of function (that's very fragile for flask, you should replace it with something more persistent)

```
chats = {}
```

Then in route function simply refer to the chat object just like you do with sessions:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    if session.get('sessionid'):
        print('sessionid already set: ',session['sessionid'])
    else:
        session['sessionid'] = uuid.uuid4().hex
    chats[session['sessionid']] = chat_model.start_chat()
    return redirect(url_for('chat'))
```

Then an analogous use when referring to it:

```
response = chats[session['sessionid']].send_message(user_input, **parameters)
```

Comment: matszwecja I can't thank you enough. That is such a simple, elegant solution and I would NEVER have thought of it. You have saved me many hours of work, I am genuinely grateful that you took the time to help.

Also, when you say "that's very fragile for flask, you should replace it with something more persistent" can you please explain what you mean?

Comment: When you run a Flask app, it is served through a WSGI. This service creates a worker that handles incoming requests. The relevant part is that it may arbitrarily restart script, (even though it looks like the app is constantly running), clearing any runtime only variables. If you want something more persistent, you need to store the data outside runtime memory.